# Serilog+Elastic, почему не создаются индексы?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, serilog

Доброго времени суток.
Настройки Serilog:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "System": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Elasticsearch",
        "Args": {
          "nodeUris": "https://172.16.0.109:9200/",
          "connectionGlobalHeaders": "Authorization=Basic ZWxhc3RpYzpwYXNzd29yZA==",
          "indexFormat": "server-logs-{0:yyyy.MM}",
          "autoRegisterTemplate": true,
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "ApplicationName": "Server"
    }
  }
}
```

```cs
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();
```

Не создаются индексы, в кибане пустота. Может быть из-за header'a с авторизацией?

Comment: Возможно, проблема заключается в конфигурации Elasticsearch. Вам нужно убедиться, что у вас есть правильные разрешения для создания индексов в Elasticsearch.

Comment: авторизуюсь от лица "elastic" с ролью superuser

Comment: Тогда даже не скажу((( может кто-то еще подскажет